# Meteor Template.registerHelper() not working within {{#if}} block

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

Defined 3 global helpers in Meteor as follows:

```
Template.registerHelper('activeTrips', function () {
    console.log("Global Active Trips");
    return Trips.find().count();
});

Template.registerHelper('isSuperUser', function () {
    console.log("Global isSuperUser");
    return Meteor.user().username === "superuser";
});

Template.registerHelpr('isAdminUser', function () {
    console.log("Global isAdmin");
    return Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin']);
});
```

Used as template count displays {{activeTrips}} displays count correctly!

But other helpers - which return True or False - do not seem to work with the handlebars {{#if}} construct?

For example {{#if isAdminUser}}  do admin stuff {{/if}} never works even if I force the function to return true - in fact the helper never gets called according to my console output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I would make sure that you have defined all three of your global template helpers in a Javascript file that is loaded only on the client (located within a 'client' directory).

Second, I would make sure that this Javascript file is loaded before your template code that uses these template helpers is loaded (for example, make sure that the Javascript file with the global template helpers is located within a 'lib' directory under the top-level 'client' directory, while the template code is located in a Javascript file in another directory, such as 'templates', under the same top-level 'client' directory).

Third, I would make sure that you spell `Template.registerHelper` properly wherever the template helper code is written (I noticed that you misspelled "registerHelper" in your code example above).

After verifying all of these things, does the code still not work as expected?

Comment: Arghhh! too much work and snow! The spelling error fixed it all - I just didn' t see it. The SuperUser test is called inside templates that use isAdminUser - so neither executed... it was bugging me that activeTrips worked and the others did not!